# CORONA SDK - facebook.showDialog() appears and disappears after a while

Tags: facebook, authentication, lua, coronasdk, showdialog

I've added Facebook to my application.

The login is ok, except that facebook.login() opens the browser instead of the native Facebook App, but then, when I call Facebook.showDialog() the popup pops up, but after a second or two it disappears.

Note that I get this behavior on iOS only, while on Android it is working fine.

I'm using the code below in my game.lua file:

```
local function facebookListener( event )

    if ( "session" == event.type ) then
      if ( "login" == event.phase ) then
            local access_token = event.token
             facebook.showDialog( "feed", { name = "SuperCool Game Coming soon", description = "Trying to figure out how to get my game to rule the world.", picture = "http://omnigeekmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/omniblaster_promo-300x300.png", link = "http://www.omnigeekmedia.com/"})
        end

    elseif ( "request" == event.type ) then
        print("facebook request")
        if ( not event.isError ) then
            local response = json.decode( event.response )

        end

    elseif ( "dialog" == event.type ) then
        print( "dialog", event.response )

    end
end

fbAppID = "my app ID"  --replace with your Facebook App ID
function logOnFacebook(event)
    if(event.phase=="ended")then
        facebook.login( fbAppID, facebookListener, { "user_friends", "publish_actions" } )
    end
end

["facebook"] =
{                
 publisherId = "com.coronalabs", 
 supportedPlatforms = { iphone = true, ["iphone-sim"] = true },
},
```

I'm running on build 2015.2729.

How can I manage to get Facebook work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating to the v4 version of the plugin. While it's technically still in beta, it's required for iOS 9 builds.  See:

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/07/24/facebook-v4-plugin-android-beta/
https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/09/01/facebook-v4-plugin-ios-beta-improvements-and-new-features/

Answer (score 0):

Browsing through the [source code of the old Facebook plugin](https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-source-facebook/blob/master/ios/Plugin/IOSFBConnect.mm), this error will occur in the event that a permission requested wasn't granted!

In the source code for the old Facebook plugin, this can be seen in the FBSessionReauthorizeResultHandlers.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < [publishPermissions count]; i++)
{
    if ( ![publishSession.permissions containsObject:[publishPermissions objectAtIndex:i]] )
    {
        release = true;
        publishError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"com.facebook" code:123 userInfo:nil];
        break;
    }
}
```

This will also occur for read permissions that were requested and not granted.

The issue has since been fixed in the [Facebook-v4 plugin](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/facebook-v4/index.html).